# How to make a loop clear cache every 100,000 loops?

Tags: excel

I have taken a code posted here somewhere and inserted an If statement that basically makes the sheet save every 10,000 loops. I read an advice somewhere that this stops excel from crashing completely. I am basically trying to match columns and finding duplicates by highlighting them/copying.

The issues is both columns that I am comparing have 100,000 rows each. I have been running the code for 4 hours now and it has only produced 1000 lines of matches... I am expecting at least 15,000 matches.

This time penalty is getting ridiculous, I am pretty sure there is a faster way to do it, but I am no expert in coding. :(

```
Sub Compare()


Dim Report As Worksheet
Dim i, j, z, colNum, vMatch As Integer
Dim lastRowA, lastRowB, lastRow, lastColumn As Integer
Dim ColumnUsage As String
Dim colA, colB, colC As String
Dim A, B, C As Variant

Set Report = Excel.ActiveSheet
vMatch = 1

'Select A and B Columns to compare
On Error Resume Next
 Set A = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select column to compare",        Title:="Column A", Type:=8)
       If A Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    colA = Split(A(1).Address(1, 0), "$")(0)
     Set B = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select column being searched",     Title:="Column B", Type:=8)
   If A Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  colB = Split(B(1).Address(1, 0), "$")(0)
 'Select Column to show results
     Set C = Application.InputBox("Select column  to show results", "Results", Type:=8)
    If C Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  colC = Split(C(1).Address(1, 0), "$")(0)

'Get Last Row
lastRowA = Report.Cells.Find("", Range(colA & 1), xlFormulas, xlByRows,      xlPrevious).row - 1 ' Last row in column A
lastRowB = Report.Cells.Find("", Range(colB & 1), xlFormulas, xlByRows, xlPrevious).row - 1 ' Last row in column B

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'***************************************************
For i = 3 To lastRowA     'change this NUMBER depending on which row the data starts
      For j = 3 To lastRowB
           z = j / 10000
          If Report.Cells(i, A.Column).Value <> "" Then
              If InStr(1, Report.Cells(j, B.Column).Value, Report.Cells(i, A.Column).Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                  vMatch = vMatch + 1
                  Report.Cells(i, A.Column).Interior.ColorIndex = 35 'Light green background
                  Range(colC & 1).Value = "Items Found"
                  Report.Cells(i, A.Column).Copy Destination:=Range(colC & vMatch)
                        If j = Int(j) Then
                            ThisWorkbook.Save
                  Exit For
              Else
                  'Do Nothing
              End If
            End If
          End If
      Next j
  Next i
If vMatch = 1 Then
    MsgBox Prompt:="No Items Found", Buttons:=vbInformation
End If
'***************************************************
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: A quick note: You do it before `.Cells`, but also before you have `Range`, add the Sheet you want to reference. IE `lastRowA = Report.Cells.Find("", Report.Range(colA & 1), xlFormulas, xlByRows,      xlPrevious)` (notice I added `Report.` before `Range`).  This will cut down on the potential for VBA to grab incorrect data.

Comment: Also, `If j = Int(j) Then ThisWorkbook.Save` doesn't make sense. It will always be true and save. Change it to `If j = lastRowB Then ThisWorkbook.Save`. This will see if it has reached 10,000. You defined z, but never used it.

Comment: still haven't seen this code complete the comparison checks. Is there a method to clear cache after an entire column has been checked against the other before moving to the next row?

Comment: What is `z` supposed to do? Also -- what do the matches look like?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code... a few points:

1. Why not make A, B, C as string which hold the column you are looking at? This will increase performance. There is no need for the split and when you are looping instead of `A.column` you can just write `A`.
2. Are you trying to find **complete** matches (as oppose to a match in part of the text)? If so, set the values into a variable e.g. `aValue = Report.Cells(j, A).Value` and `bValue = Report.Cells(j, B).Value` and then compare them using `if aValue = bValue then`
3. Are you comparing one column against another, and then displaying results in a third column if there is a match in the **SAME** row? If so, what is the purpose of the `j` loop? Just loop through i (which will be your row) and compare value in both column A and column B.

If value can be on any row in the second column, then yes you can use the `j` loop, but an even faster way will be to use Excel in-built find function in VBA where you will search your value on column B:B. Using Excel Find in VBA is *significantly* faster.

4. What is `z`?
5. Worksheet save will only fail if bigger than the bounds of type `Int`. Is that what you want?
6. Your indentation needs to be corrected.

   ```
             Exit For
         Else
             'Do Nothing
         End If
   ```

Above needs to be indented 2-3 times

Implement the above improvements and let me know how you get on. Good luck.